# Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax how can i solve it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, record

i'm new to php and mysql.

i try to update record in my database from a html form.

i have a search page that work and a edit page whit a $_GET in the link where is the id of the element i have to edit in the database.

all work the form show me the correct data, i can edit them in the form. but when i click the edit button i get this error msg:

```
Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

my php code of the edit page is this:

```
<?php
require('includes\dbconn.php');
require('includes\dbfunction.php');
session_start();


if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
  include('includes\theme\head.php');
  include('includes\theme\topbar.php');
  include('includes\theme\sidebar.php');
?>

<!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:43px;">

  <div class="w3-container">
    <div class="w3-row">
      <div class="w3-col s12 l3">
        <br>
        <?php
        //RICEVI DATI ARTICOLO DAL DATABASE
        if(isset($_GET['art_id'])){
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM articoli WHERE id =". $_GET['art_id'];
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
          }

        //AGGIORNA DATI ARTICOLO NEL DATABASE
        if(isset($_POST['btn-aggiorna'])){
          $codiceArt = $_POST['codicearticolo'];
          $descrizioneArt = $_POST['nomearticolo'];
          $barcodeArt = $_POST['barcode'];
          $prezzoAcquistoArt = $_POST['prezzoacquisto'];
          $prezzoVenditaArt = $_POST['prezzovendita'];
          $quantitaArt = $_POST['quantita'];
          $scontoArt = $_POST['sconto'];

          $update = "
UPDATE articoli 
   SET codiceArticolo='$codiceArt'
     , nomeArticolo='$descrizioneArt'
     , barcode='$barcodeArt'
     , prezzoAcquisto='$prezzoAcquistoArt'
     , prezzoVendita='$prezzoVenditaArt'
     , quantita='$quantitaArt'
     , scontoPercentuale='$scontoArt' 
 WHERE id =". $_GET['art_id'];
          if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              window.location.href = 'articolomodificato.php';
            </script>
            <?php
          } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
          }


        }

         ?>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s12 l5">

         <form class="w3-container" action="modificaarticolo.php" method="post">
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Codice articolo:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="codicearticolo" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['codiceArticolo'];?>"><br>
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Descrizione articolo:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="nomearticolo" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['nomeArticolo']; ?>"><br>
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Barcode:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="barcode" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['barcode']; ?>"><br>
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Prezzo Acquisto:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="prezzoacquisto" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['prezzoAcquisto']; ?>"><br>
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Prezzo Vendita:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="prezzovendita" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['prezzoVendita']; ?>"><br>
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Quantità:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="quantita" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['quantita']; ?>"><br>
           <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Sconto %:</b></label>
           <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="sconto" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['scontoPercentuale']; ?>"><br>
           <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" name="btn-aggiorna" type="submit">Modifica</button>
           <a class="w3-btn w3-blue" href="/bk2/magazzino.php">Indietro<a>
         </form>

      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s12 l3">
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>




  </div>
</div>











<?php
  include('includes\theme\script.php');
  ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else{
  header("location: accessonegato.php");
}
?>
```

i know from the error message the error is in my query code but i don't understand where. i had try multiple time to change the &_GET['art_id'] position in and out of the double quote of the query but noting work.

Comment: Can you show us the UPDATE alone?

Comment: Looks like one of the values you are trying to set in you update query is undefined.

Comment: Did you `echo $update` to see if your query is valid?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the ID to the form when calling the page, otherwise it's not being passed in

```
<form class="w3-container" action="modificaarticolo.php?art_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="post">
```

You may need to alter `$row['id']` to have the correct column name.

Although this will cause a slight problem, as the data is fetched in

```
//RICEVI DATI ARTICOLO DAL DATABASE
if(isset($_GET['art_id'])){
```

which is before the update, so you may need to move this code below the update to ensure it retrieves the latest data.